# ArcPy: Populating array column with rank values

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, numpy, array, rank

I am trying to get the rank values for some values in my fields. I have created an array from fields of an attribute table, sorted them in descending order, and I now want to populate the third column with the rank values. The code below should show what I am trying to do. The current error I am getting is 'too many indices for array'.

Code 'so far':

```py
def Rank_fields (in_table, field):
    arcpy.AddField_management(in_table, field[0:3]+"_rank", "LONG")
    arr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray (in_table, ["nuts315cd", field, field[0:3]+"_rank"])
    arr_sort = np.sort(arr, order=field)
    descending_array = arr_sort[::-1]
    max_numb = len(descending_array)
    descending_array.index[:, 2]+1
    print descending_array
```

Current output:

`[(u'UKJ25', 0.3, 0) (u'UKJ36', 0.28, 0) (u'UKJ44', 0.25, 0) (u'UKJ26', 0.24, 0) (u'UKJ21', 0.24, 0) (u'UKJ11', 0.24, 0)]`

Desired output:

`[(u'UKJ25', 0.3, 1) (u'UKJ36', 0.28, 2) (u'UKJ44', 0.25, 3) (u'UKJ26', 0.24, 4) (u'UKJ21', 0.24, 5) (u'UKJ11', 0.24, 6)`

Comment: check out this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy-without-sorting-array-twice) for ranking values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArcPy: Using Numpy and UpdateCursor to find value ranks](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409108/arcpy-using-numpy-and-updatecursor-to-find-value-ranks)